# Variable {$css_dir} {$js_dir} not defined en Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, cms

Viendo la documentación para crear temas, utilizan las variables `{$css_dir}` / `{$js_dir}` para poder acceder a las carpetas correspondientes del tema.

Tengo las carpetas creadas e intento usar las variables de la siguiente forma en mi `head.tpl`

```
{block name='hook_header'}
  {$HOOK_HEADER nofilter}
  <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$css_dir}icons/estilos.css" />
{/block}
```

Pero siempre me dice que la variable no existe y me da error.
¿Hay que ponerlo de alguna otra forma? Me ocurre intentando usar tanto la de css como la de js.
La versión con la que estoy trabajando es Prestashop 1.7

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema. No se si el 1.7 tiene soporte para estas variables.

Comment: Creo que aún está muy verde esta versión de prestashop...quizás tire más por algo tipo Woocommerce creo @iLevi